# Can my baby travel to Greece with an ID card instead of a passport?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, greece, bangladeshi-citizens, eu-id-card

We are from Bangladesh and live in Belgium where my husband is doing his Ph.D. We have a 6-month-old baby who was born in Belgium. He is a citizen of Bangladesh. 
Belgium does not give citizenship by birth.

We have applied for his passport at our embassy, but unfortunately it was not ready in time for our vacation in Greece.

My baby has an ID card, can he travel with just his ID card?

Comment: Is it a Belgian ID Card? Is your baby a Belgian citizen?

Answer (score 10):

If your baby is a Belgian **citizen** with a Belgian ID card, then he can travel to Greece using it.

Otherwise, he officially needs a passport and residence permit, but unless flying on a budget carrier, you probably won't be asked for ID at all unless you check in luggage.